# Reading cell value

Tags: excel, vba

So I have created a macro which is sending an email via outlook. I am stuck at some point. I need to include new cell values and corresponding cell values on top of the column in the body of an email. So basically I need my macro to read those two values.

This is my module:

```
Sub SendEmail()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
        Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        'So I want to send an email with cell new value and top of the column 
        'value corresponding to that cell
        'Example: I wanna change cell C3 from A to X and I want to include 
        'that change in body of my email automatically
        'So it reads "New cell value is X on 3-06"

        olMail.To = "*****@*****.com"
        olMail.Subject = "Look what has been changed"
            olMail.Body = "Hi" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "New cell value is <Here is new cell value> on <Top of the column 
             of that cell value> " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "BR"
        olMail.Send
End Sub
```

And this is my macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A3:AP3")) Is Nothing Then SendEmail
End Sub
```

And this is a part of the worksheet I am working on:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems you are facing is that the `Target` can be multiple cells and one `Worksheet_Change` change can be over multiple cells at the same time, not just once cell. You could check if the Target is one cell size, and do nothing if more than `1, 1` size, but then you would loose that change or parts of it at least.

An approach would be to hold a history of the changes, and send that email even if the changes are over multiple cells at once.

With that in mind, you should create an additional sheet that holds last changes, say sheet *History Sheet*.

In the sheet your working on, place in the code part of the sheet:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A3:AP3")) Is Nothing Then
        checkHistory Target.Worksheet.Range("A3:AP3")
    End If
End Sub
```

In any module in the same workbook, add this:

```vb
Sub checkHistory(rng As Range)
Dim wsHistory As Worksheet: Set wsHistory = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("History Sheet")
Dim arrData As Variant, arrHistory As Variant
Dim R As Long, C As Long
Dim bChanges As Boolean

arrData = rng.Offset(-2).Resize(3)
arrHistory = wsHistory.Range(rng.Offset(-2).Resize(3).Address)

Dim arrChanges() As String: ReDim arrChanges(LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData), LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2))

For C = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
    If arrData(3, C) <> arrHistory(3, C) Then
        arrChanges(3, C) = arrData(3, C)
        If Not bChanges Then bChanges = True
    End If
Next C

If bChanges Then
    Dim strNewVal As String, strHeading As String

    wsHistory.Range(rng.Offset(-2).Resize(3).Address) = arrData
    For C = LBound(arrChanges, 2) To UBound(arrChanges, 2)
        If arrChanges(3, C) <> "" Then
            strNewVal = strNewVal & ", " & arrChanges(3, C)  'new values
            strHeading = strHeading & ", " & arrData(1, C) 'heading
        End If
    Next C

    strNewVal = Right(strNewVal, Len(strNewVal) - 2)
    strHeading = Right(strHeading, Len(strHeading) - 2)

    SendEmail strNewVal, strHeading
End If
End Sub

Sub SendEmail(strNewVal As String, strHeading As String)
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
        Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        olMail.To = "*****@*****.com"
        olMail.Subject = "Look what has been changed"
            olMail.Body = "Hi" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "New cell value is " & strNewVal & " on " & strHeading & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "BR"
        olMail.Send
End Sub
```

With the above, you would send that email regardless if the change is over 1 cell, or more, as comma separated values.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. This just worked perfectly. You are great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some small changes:

```
Sub SendEmail(rng As Range)
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application, c As Range, bdy

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<< nothing to report

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
        Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        olMail.To = "*****@*****.com"
        olMail.Subject = "Look what has been changed"
        bdy = "Hi" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

        'check each changed cell
        For Each c in rng.Cells             
            bdy = bdy & "New cell value is '" & c.Value & _
                  "' on " & c.EntireColumn.Cells(1).Value & _
                  vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        Next c  

        olMail.Body = bdy & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "BR"
        olMail.Send
End Sub
```

Event handler:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    SendEmail Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A3:AP3"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Unfortunately this way I get entire string pasted into email body. Anyway it helped me. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure what "the entire string" means here, but it looks like you got a good answer from FAB.